# "Failed to decode output: Error: hex data is odd-length (argument=\"value\", value=\"0x0\", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.7.0)"

Tags: solidity, error

I used these functions for my TicTacToe contract but it gives an error. This contract uses Minimax algorithm to find optimal way to play against a player. I have to use makeMoveY function inside the function when player uses to make a move. (When the player makes the move, makeMoveY function will be executed and computer will counter-play.)

My functions are below:

```
function makeMove(
    uint256 _gameID,
    uint256 _xCoordinate,
    uint256 _yCoordinate
) public returns (bool success, string memory reason) {
    if (_gameID > nrOfGames) return (false, "No such game exists.");

    Game storage game = games[_gameID - 1];

    if (game.winner != Winners.None)
        return (false, "The game has already ended.");

    if (msg.sender != getCurrentPlayer(game))
        return (false, "It is not your turn.");

    if (game.board[_xCoordinate][_yCoordinate] != Players.None)
        return (false, "There is already a mark at the given coordinates.");

    game.board[_xCoordinate][_yCoordinate] = game.playerTurn;

    emit PlayerMadeMove(_gameID, msg.sender, _xCoordinate, _yCoordinate);

    Winners winner = calculateWinner(game.board);
    if (winner != Winners.None) {
        game.winner = winner;
        emit GameOver(_gameID, winner);

        return (true, "The game is over.");
    }

    nextPlayer(game);

    if (game.gameType == GameType.PlayerVsComputer) {
        makeMoveY(game, game.board);
        return (true, "Computer played. Your turn again");
    }

    return (true, "");
}

function MiniMax(
    Players[3][3] storage _board,
    uint256 _depth,
    bool _isMax
) private returns (int256) {
    if (calculateWinner(_board) == Winners.PlayerOne) return 10;
    if (calculateWinner(_board) == Winners.PlayerTwo) return -10;

    if (isBoardFull(_board)) return 0;

    int256 best;

    if (_isMax) {
        best = -1000;

        for (uint8 i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (uint8 j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (_board[i][j] == Players.None){
                        _board[i][j] == Players.PlayerOne;
                        best = max(best, MiniMax(_board, _depth + 1, !_isMax));
                        _board[i][j] = Players.None;
                }
            }
        }
        return best;
    } else {
        best = 1000;

        for (uint8 i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (uint8 j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (_board[i][j] == Players.None)
                    {
                        _board[i][j] == Players.PlayerTwo;
                        best = min(best, MiniMax(_board, _depth + 1, !_isMax));
                        _board[i][j] = Players.None;
                    }
            }
        }
        return best;
    }
}
 
function findBestMoveY(Players[3][3] storage _board)
    private
    returns (uint8[2] memory)
{
    int256 bestVal = 1000;
    int256 moveVal;
    uint8[2] memory bestMove;

    for (uint8 i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (uint8 j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (_board[i][j] == Players.None) {
                _board[i][j] = Players.PlayerTwo;

                moveVal = MiniMax(_board, 0, true);

                _board[i][j] = Players.None;

                if (moveVal < bestVal) {
                    bestMove[0] = i;
                    bestMove[1] = j;
                    bestVal = moveVal;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return bestMove;
}

function makeMoveY(Game storage _game, Players[3][3] storage _board)
    private
    returns (bool success, string memory reason)
{
    if (_game.playerTurn != Players.PlayerTwo)
        return (false, "Not second players turn");
    uint8[2] memory move = findBestMoveY(_board);
    _board[move[0]][move[1]] = Players.PlayerTwo;
    nextPlayer(_game);
    return (true, "");
}
```

Error line:

```
"error": "Failed to decode output: Error: hex data is odd-length (argument=\"value\", value=\"0x0\", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.7.0)"
```

I am a newbie here, so I might have skipped any information. Please let me know if I am missing anything that you should have. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Which function are you calling? It could be the contract has an error and it isn't returning the expected value.

Comment: I called MakeMoveY function and it gave this error.

Comment: I concluded that the error was caused by the recursion that I used in the MiniMax function, but I still cannot understand why it caused an error. Can you look into that, please? @Ismael

Comment: You are using recursion, so it could had run out of gas. Reading and writing from storage is expensive. Try to avoid long iterations, or recursion.

Comment: Is there any chance to increase gas limit or can I use iterations with smaller integers (uint16 etc.) ? I have to use recursion because of the algorithm.

Comment: The EVM is a constrained environment. In mainnet you can use up to 30M gas. With ganache you can set to a much larger value.

Comment: I set it to the limit of int64 but still it was trying to execute but nothing happened. I developed these functions in Python and it works but not in Solidity. What problem could it be, can you help if you can understand, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by using Alpha-Beta pruning. Alpha-beta pruning is a developed version of the minimax algorithm that eliminates the worst moves and reduces the workload.

```
// alpha beta pruning
function alphabeta(
    Players[3][3] memory state,
    uint8 depth,
    int256 alpha,
    int256 beta,
    bool isMaximizing
) internal view returns (int256) {
    if (
        depth == 0 ||
        calculateWinner(state) != Winners.None ||
        isBoardFull(state)
    ) {
        return evaluate(state);
    }

    if (isMaximizing) {
        int256 maxScore = int256(type(int).min);
        for (uint8 i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (uint8 j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (state[i][j] == Players.None) {
                    Players[3][3] memory newState = state;
                    newState[i][j] = Players.PlayerOne;
                    int256 score = alphabeta(
                        newState,
                        depth - 1,
                        alpha,
                        beta,
                        !isMaximizing
                    );
                    maxScore = int256(max(int(score), int(maxScore)));
                    alpha = int256(max(int(maxScore), int(alpha)));
                    if (beta <= alpha) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return maxScore;
    } else {
        int256 minScore = int256(type(int).max);
        for (uint8 i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (uint8 j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (state[i][j] == Players.None) {
                    Players[3][3] memory newState = state;
                    newState[i][j] = Players.PlayerTwo;
                    int256 score = alphabeta(
                        newState,
                        depth - 1,
                        alpha,
                        beta,
                        !isMaximizing
                    );
                    minScore = int256(min(int(score), int(minScore)));
                    beta = int256(min(int(minScore), int(beta)));
                    if (beta <= alpha) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return minScore;
    }
}
```

You can use it, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this error when testing out the [Chainlink VRF](https://docs.chain.link/vrf) demo contract (specifically when calling the `rollDice` method). My issue was that I had not added the contract address as an approved consumer in the Chainlink VRF [Subscription Manager](https://vrf.chain.link/).

**1. Copy the deployed contract address**

[image]

**2. Add the address as a consumer in the Subscription Manager**

[image]

**3. Wait for confirmation**

Once you see that the address has been added, you should be able to call the `rollDice` method without error.

See the [How do I Deploy to Testnet](https://docs.chain.link/vrf/v2/getting-started#how-do-i-deploy-to-testnet) section for the official instructions.